# Should we post bugs for Windows 8.1 phone?

Tags: discussion

I have a Windows application Phone with Windows 8.1.
As I use SO on its browser I find several issues. Should I report them as bugs?

I found only one bug reported here for Windows Phone and the comments indicated it was not officially supported.

Yet, the bugs I find in my phone may actually be issues on SO that other browsers more "intelligent" handle better, but still SO issues.
I understand the position for not creating a dedicated app for Windows Phone. But, Microsoft is still a major player in IT, and I think solving issues the Site has when visualized in their browser would be valuable. Of course as long it is an issue in the site and not a problem of the browser not being capable of doing something that it should.

Comment: "Microsoft is still a major player in IT" Well, yeah, that's why desktop IE is supported. Windows has a massive desktop market share, but its mobile presence is all but insignificant in many developed countries. Windows Phone *is* pretty big in some developed parts of Europe and in India, the latter of which constitutes a plurality of Stack Overflow users, but even so there are still way more Android and iOS questions simply because that's where the global market is.

Comment: @BoltClock - They claim (Microsoft) that the browser/apps in different devices have (or should have) a very similar experience.

Comment: Well you *are* intending to report a bug only exhibited on IE11 Mobile, right?

Comment: @BoltClock - Also it still is the 3rd in market share (lol really far behind). In any case many Devs wind up with Windows Phone because their desktop apps are windows and need to do and test a mobile version, not necessarily by choice. That is why I said "it would be valuable". Regarding your question, I have windows phone, but not (yet) windows 8 machine, so I can't be sure it happens also there. I am asking just because if those "bugs" are not well received it is a waste of time to post them, but if they are considered at least "valuable information" I wouldn't mind posting them.

Comment: @Dzyann Either way, I don't think windows phone is supported is it?

Comment: @Tim - yes as far as I know it is not supported, that is why I am asking if I should report them or not bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to post bugs you experience when using the Stack Exchange sites.

Bug reports still require research, like

- searching for duplicates on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tags=bug) and [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tags=bug),
- reproduction steps,
- links to posts/pages where the bug appears,
- possible workarounds,
- impact on general usability and a
- [check if your browser/plartform is on the supported list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100).

Posts tagged with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) are gathered network-wide, although [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) seems to be the most dominant site for reports on the apps for [iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tags=ios-app?tags=ios-app) and [Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tags=android-app).

Remember that posting a bug-report doesn't guarantee that it gets fixed, not even within the 6 to 8 weeks timeframe. But when a feature is touched and a fix is possible you might get lucky, even if your bug is on a non-supported platform/browser.

To manage your expectation up-front: Bug reports will get up-votes if users can repro a bug but I have seen bug-reports that were legit bugs but considered so minor that they were greeted with down votes, signaling *don't spend developer resources on this*.

Comment: Great, thanks! This is what I want to know. Since the platform is not supported for me it was a gray area to call them bugs. Also thanks for pointing out the correct way for posting a bug. And yes I understand if it doesn't get fixed right away or ever, considering the circumstances, but if there is not even a record of it, I guess it is even less likely it will get fixed.